# jQuery .before/.after is not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Why `.before/.after` is not working? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj5RW/) I think there is something wrong with selectors or HTML structure, but I don´t see it.

```
<div class="kontakty">
    <div class="row">
        <a id="link-anchor-form" href="/kontakty/#form_form1">
           <div class="collapsing-link clearfix"> 
              <h2 id="go-form-button">something</h2>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsing-link clearfix">sadad</div>
    <div class="collapsing-link clearfix">sadad</div>
    <div class="collapsing-link clearfix">sadad</div>
    <div class="collapsing-link clearfix">sadad</div>
</div>


$('.kontakty > div.collapsing-link:first-child').after($('.kontakty .row #link-anchor-form')).addClass('moved');
```

Comment: Always put all of the relevant code and markup **in** the question, don't just link, not even to jsFiddle. A fiddle is a nice add-on, not a substitue. This is your **sixth** question, you should be doing this yourself without help by now.

Comment: Ok, thank you, next time I will do it.

Comment: Looks like you don't know how the `:first-child` selector works. Have a look at some documentation: https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.kontakty > div.collapsing-link:first-child` doesn't match anything. The `:first-child` of `.kontakty` isn't a member of `.collapsing-link`.

You probably want to use:

```
 $('.kontakty > div.collapsing-link').first()
```

instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — No, to `<div class="row">`.

Comment: Or just remove the `-child` part: `$('.kontakty > div.collapsing-link:first')`

Comment: @Quentin: I'm getting what you're saying now. I would put it differently, but it's just a phrasing thing (and I'm not saying my way of putting it would be better).